# Deploying Create-React-App to Multiple URLs

Tags: reactjs, react-router, create-react-app

I want to be able to build the same CRA app and deploy it both to www.homepage.com/`beta` and www.homepage.com/`web`

The reason is so that I can deploy a different version to my beta users while having a non-beta version of the site up for the other users.

I changed my ROUTEs in `React-Router` to handle whether a url has `/web/` or `/beta/` and it was working locally but when I deployed and went to homepage.com/beta my Routes are rendering.

I have narrowed it down to my `package.json` where it has the `homepage` property. If it use `homepage.com/beta` then the beta site works. If I use `homepage.com` or `homepage.com/web/` then the beta stops working properly.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I would go for the subdomain solution (beta.homepage.com) which will aditionally allow proper site storage & cookie separation between beta and not beta deployments

Comment: So I would set the `homepage` property to `www.homepage.com` in `package.json` but how would I be able to tell my app which version to load? Would I need to maintain two codebases?

Comment: I think that different versions of the application are supposed to be in different codebases (see also https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#version).

The "homepage" property seems to have another purpose (https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#homepage).

Comment: In that case, the routing would be performed via the web server configuration (e.g. for nginx http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html)